# Validation rules conflict on model scenarios yii

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have validation rules for model as follows

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    //post of step 1
    if (isset($_POST['yt0']))
    {
        return array(
                array('EmailAddress,', 'required','message' =>  Yii::t('message', 'USERNAME_REQUIRED')),
                array('Password,', 'required','message' =>  Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_REQUIRED')),
                array('confirmPassword,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'CONFIRM_PASSWORD_REQUIRED')),
                array('Password','length', 'max' => 100, 'min' => 6, 'tooShort' => Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_LENGTH')),
                array('confirmPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'Password','message' => Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_COMPARE')),
                array('EmailId,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'EMAILID_REQUIRED')),
                array('EmailId','email','message'=>Yii::t('message', 'EMAILID_VALID')),
                array('chapterCode,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'CHAPTERCODE_REQUIRED')),
                array('verifyCode,', 'required','message' =>Yii::t('message', 'VERIFYCODE_REQUIRED')),
                array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'caseSensitive'=>true,'message' =>Yii::t('message', 'VERIFYCODE_INCORRECT') ),
                array('EmailAddress', 'unique','className'=>'User','attributeName'=>'EmailAddress','message'=>Yii::t('message', 'EMAILID_UNIQUE')),
                array('PersonId', 'unique','className'=>'User','attributeName'=>'PersonId','message'=>"Person already exists."),
                array('FailedLoginCount', 'safe'),
        );
    }   elseif (isset($_POST['yt1']))
    {
        return array(
                array('EmailAddress,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'USERNAME_REQUIRED')),
                array('Password,', 'required','message' =>  Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_REQUIRED')),
                array('FailedLoginCount', 'safe'),

        );
    }elseif (isset($_POST['savecontact'])||$this->memBelongsto==0)
    {
        return array(
                array('EmailAddress,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'USERNAME_REQUIRED')),
                array('Password,', 'required','message' =>  Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_REQUIRED')),
                array('confirmPassword', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'CONFIRM_PASSWORD_REQUIRED')),
                array('Password','length', 'max' => 100, 'min' => 6,'tooShort' => Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_LENGTH')),
                array('confirmPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'Password','message' => Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_COMPARE')),
                array('EmailId,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'EMAILID_REQUIRED'),'except'=>'datavalid'),
                array('EmailId','email','message'=>Yii::t('message', 'EMAILID_VALID'),'except'=>'datavalid'),
                array('FailedLoginCount', 'safe'),

        );
    }else{
        return array(
                array('EmailAddress,EmailId, Password', 'required'),
                array('PersonId, ActiveFlag, FailedLoginCount', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                array('EmailAddress, Password', 'length', 'max'=>100),
                array('confirmPassword,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_REQUIRED')),
                array('Password','length', 'max' => 100, 'min' => 6, 'tooShort' => Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_LENGTH')),
                array('confirmPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'Password','message' => Yii::t('message', 'PASSWORD_COMPARE')),
                array('chapterCode,', 'required','message' => Yii::t('message', 'CHAPTERCODE_REQUIRED')),
                array('verifyCode,', 'required','message' =>Yii::t('message', 'VERIFYCODE_REQUIRED')),
                array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'caseSensitive'=>true,'message' =>Yii::t('message', 'VERIFYCODE_INCORRECT')),
                array('FailedLoginCount', 'safe'),
        );
    }
}
```

and here `yt0` is name of submit button on signup page and so for signup the rules of `yt0` will be applied and I have another form for change password so on that page I need only three fields and the submit button for change password is `savecontact` and but savecontact rules are applied but the signup button rules are conflicting so the validation on signup is not working . Is it right way to right rules as above any suggestions please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while this may work, you are doing it in the wrong approach.
You should use `scenario` to perform these kind of tasks.

First of all, you can declare scenarios for your different forms:

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
    const SCENARIO_SIGNUP = 'signup';
    const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';
}
```

When you are done with defining scenarios, you can tell your model what attributes to use for massive assignment and apply validation for the specific scenarios.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
    const SCENARIO_REGISTER = 'register';
    const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_LOGIN => ['username', 'password'],
            self::SCENARIO_REGISTER => ['email', 'username', 'password'],
            self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['email', 'username', 'password'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Now that you are done, you can choose to add validation rules or use the default one generated by gii.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_LOGIN = 'login';
    const SCENARIO_REGISTER = 'register';
    const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';

    public function scenarios()
    {
        return [
            self::SCENARIO_LOGIN => ['username', 'password'],
            self::SCENARIO_REGISTER => ['email', 'username', 'password'],
            self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['email', 'username', 'password'],
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge([
            ['email' => 'email', 'message' => Yii::t('message', 'wrong email format')],
            [['email', 'password', 'username'] => 'email'],
            ['username', 'exist', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN], // this will apply only on login
            // other rules
        ], parent::rules());
    }
}
```

Now that you are done with your model scenarios and rules, time to use them correctly.

Head to your controller and instantiate your models using the scenarios:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model = new User(['scenario' => User::SCENARIO_LOGIN]);

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // $model will have username and password even if email is in the form since it is using
        // User::SCENARIO_LOGIN
        $model->validate(); 
        // will validate only username and password even if email is in the form
        // will also use the username exist validator
        // do your stuff
    }
}

public function actionRegister()
{
    $model = new User(['scenario' => User::SCENARIO_REGISTER]);

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // $model will have username, password and email
        $model->validate(); 
        // will validate email, username and password but will not use the
        // username exist validation rule since it has the `'on' => self::SCENARIO_LOGIN`
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Go to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html for more details about how to properly use models and validations

Comment: thanks brother for reply and i will try this and i will ask if any doubts